# error 1: command not find on simple conditional bash scripting exercise

Tags: bash, shell-script

i've been doing a command line course on codecademy and i get an error that i can't figure out why it's there.

i enter this code in my script.sh file:

```
01 #!/bin/bash
02 first_greeting="Nice to meet you!"
03 later_greeting="How are you?"
04 greeting_occasion=0
05 
06 
07 if [$greeting_occasion -lt 1]
08 then
09   echo $first_greeting
10 else
11   echo $later_greeting
12 fi
```

And when i run on bash i get this:

```
$./script.sh
./script/sh: line 6: [1: command not found
How are you?
```

I´ve tried changing `greeting_occasion` value but the result is always `How are you?` with an error on line 6. Also, i tried changing the conditional to start on line 5, and i get the same error on the same line, line 6, and the same result `How are you?`.

Any ideas on what´s up in this?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Welcome! You can use [https://www.shellcheck.net/](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to test your code.

Comment: There is a command line version of shellcheck. On Debian install with `apt install shellcheck`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a space `[ $greeting_occasion -lt 1 ]`.

The `$greeting_occasion` was transformed to a `1`.
this gave

```
if [1 -lt 1]
```

So bash tried to run `[1`, with arguments `-lt`, and `1]` and pass its exit code to `if`